# Pulling page layout changes from scratch org includes element reordering

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm seeing that sometimes when I edit a page layout on scratch org, when just changing a few field parameters (setting to read-only, removing extra spaces) and then issuing a `sfdx force:source:pull` also includes changes not explicitly done in the layout editor, like  rearranging the Global Action order of appearance.  This is quite annoying because I have to spot this and when pulling and then do a change of this again on the scratch org and pull again.  Has anyone else seen this behaviour?  This does not happen every time, and not on all page layouts, which makes this harder for me to spot a pattern.